# Levono ThinkPad yoga 11e

Tags: windows-10

I have been trying to enable intel (R) virtualization technology. But I couldn't access the option to enable virtualization.
My question is what can I do to make choices under BIOS ( to enable virtualization technology)

Comment: LMGTFY: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-yoga-series-laptops/thinkpad-yoga-11e/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers

Comment: If the option to enable VT-x, does not exist, then there really isn't anything that can be done about that. Some OEM devices prevent VT-x from being enabled.